# Attempted to read or write protected memory when trying to pass large sequence of characters in C#

Tags: c#, c, string, dll, char

I'm working on a tag reader and i was able to connect it and read some data. My problem is when I attempt to read the tag id which is a large sequence of characters.

The SDK is in C language and I'm developing a c# application.

```
short GetIDBuffer(HANDLE hCom, unsigned char* DataFlag, unsigned char * Count, 
      unsigned char *value, unsigned char* StationNum)
```

In my C# application:

```
[DllImport("Reader2.dll",CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
public static extern short GetIDBuffer(IntPtr hCom, ref uint DataFlag, 
       ref uint Count, ref String value, ref uint StationNum);
```

**Dataflag, count, station number** are mainly small sequences where a uint type is doing well.  But when it comes to **value** it's a large sequence. I tried the type **string** but it's throwing this exception:

> Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an
>   indication that other memory is corrupt.

- **[MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)]string value**

  didnt solve the problem
- **count** value is returned correctly
- My operating system is 64 bit: i used `corflags application.exe/32bit+` and i was able to load the dll correctly.

code snapshot:

```
 [DllImport("Reader2.dll")] 
    public static extern byte OpenReader(ref IntPtr hCom, byte LinkType, string com_port, uint port);
    [DllImport("Reader2.dll")]
    public static extern  short GetIDBuffer(IntPtr hCom, ref byte DataFlag, ref byte Count,**(type)** value , ref byte StationNum);

    static  void Main(string[] args)
    {

        byte count = 0, station = 1, flag = 0;
        IntPtr hcom = IntPtr.Zero;        
        OpenReader(ref hcom, 2, "192.168.0.178", 4001);
        // valid handle returned from openReader 
      //
        **GetIDBuffer code**
            //
```

Comment: Use a StringBuilder instead, drop *ref*.  Be sure to initialize it with a large enough Capacity.  Guessing it wrong corrupts the heap.

Comment: tank you hans,
 StringBuilder value = new StringBuilder("test",1000);
returns" {} " no values.
any ideas?

Comment: Looks good, the pinvoke call at least reset the builder back to an empty string.  No idea why of course.

Comment: since count has the same type char*. i tried the stringbuilder on count and it's no longer returning the correct values. @hans any ideas now ?

Comment: You are just wildly trying now.  No way that a variable named "count" is a string.  Sanely anyway.  Those other arguments are probably `ref byte`.  The function signature is lousy, talk to the guy that wrote the code.  Yell a bit to make yourself feel better :)

Comment: Do you have the C source code?  If so can we see the GetIDBuffer function?

Comment: @Phil the definition from .h file is mentioned above
**short GetIDBuffer(HANDLE hCom, unsigned char* DataFlag, unsigned char * Count, 
      unsigned char *value, unsigned char* StationNum)**. no c source code, just the .h and the dll.

Comment: Since Count is ref byte*, its largest value can be 255. This means that your data cannot be too large, so your C signature is probably wrong.

Comment: count value is returned correctly.
my main problem is the parameter **value**
i know from the sdk that it's a large sequence of characters
**ex: if 9 tags are in the buffer, _value_ will return the id of all tags in the same time in a predefined pattern**

i tried ulong uint just to see if it returns a value. it returned but wrong one.

stringbuilder returned an empty string

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You shouldn't need to use *corflags application.exe/32bit+*.  All you need to do is set the platform target to x86 in project/properties/build.

This will work (well it does using a test native method I created with the same signature as given above).
This first method doesn't require the *unsafe* keyword, or require the project to be built with 'Allow unsafe code' set to true.

```
internal static class NativeMethods
{
    [DllImport("Reader2.dll")]
    public static extern short GetIDBuffer(
           IntPtr hCom, ref byte dataFlag, ref byte count, 
           byte [] value, ref byte stationNum);
}

static int TestGetIDBuffer()
{
    const int arraySize = 255;
    byte[] bytes = new byte[arraySize + 1]; 

    byte dataFlag = 0;
    byte count = arraySize;
    byte status = 0;

    int retval = NativeMethods.GetIdBuffer(IntPtr.Zero, ref dataFlag, ref count, bytes, ref status);

    Debug.WriteLine(Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytes));
    Debug.WriteLine(dataFlag);
    Debug.WriteLine(status);
    Debug.WriteLine(count);
    Debug.WriteLine(retval);

    return retval;
}
```

Here's an alternative using a *fixed* array of bytes.
This second method requires the *unsafe* keyword, and also that the project is built with 'Allow unsafe code' set to true.

```
internal static class NativeMethods
{
    [DllImport("Reader2.dll")]
    public static extern unsafe short GetIDBuffer(
           IntPtr hCom, ref byte dataFlag, ref byte count, 
           byte* value, ref byte stationNum);
}

static unsafe int TestGetIDBuffer()
{
    const int arraySize = 255;
    byte[] bytes = new byte[arraySize + 1];

    byte dataFlag = 0;
    byte count = arraySize;
    byte status = 0;

    int retval;
    fixed (byte* buffer = bytes)
    retval = NativeMethods.GetIdBuffer(
             IntPtr.Zero, ref dataFlag, ref count, buffer, ref status);

    Debug.WriteLine(Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytes));
    Debug.WriteLine(dataFlag);
    Debug.WriteLine(status);
    Debug.WriteLine(count);
    Debug.WriteLine(retval);

    return retval;
}
```

The dataFlag, count and stationNum all seem to be in/out byte values.

The data buffer being filled is an array of byte.  This buffer needs to fixed so that the GC won't move it while you're calling the native method.  This is done implicitly in the first example, and explicitly in the second.

I'm assuming the available buffer size should be passed into the method in the count parameter, and that this value on exit will be the amount of buffer used. I've allowed an extra byte to ensure there's a null terminating character if the array of bytes needs to converted to a string.

There are actually two forms of the *fixed* statement.  One mentioned in this [MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zycewsya%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) allows you to create fixed size array, as in
    public fixed byte Bytes [ArraySize];
The other in this [MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f58wzh21%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) allow you to pin the location of a variable in order to take it's address.

Here's my C++ test code:

```
extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) unsigned short __stdcall GetIDBuffer( 
    HANDLE hCom, unsigned char * dataFlag, unsigned char * count, 
    unsigned char* buffer,  unsigned char * status )
{
    memset(buffer, 0x1E, *count);

    *dataFlag = 0xa1;
    *count = 0x13;
    *status = 0xfe;

    return 0x7531;
}
```

The only difference between the C# code given above and my test code is that the entry point has to be specified differently since I used the C++ compiler, e.g.

```
[DllImport("PInvokeTestLib.dll", EntryPoint = "_GetIDBuffer@20")]
public static extern unsafe short GetIdBuffer(...
```

You can safely specify the parameters passed to the method (not including the value array parameter) as primitive types other than byte, such as int, long etc.  This is because 1) the values are passed in reference and 2) x86 uses little-endian byte ordering.  This results in the single byte being written to the least significant byte of the four byte int passed in.

It's advisable to use matching types though, byte in this case.

Comment: there is no need to fix it unless the unmanaged code writes to the buffer after the call returns.  In the normal case you can just pass a byte array and have the CLR worry about fixing buffers/marshaling data.

Comment: I've tried without fixing.  I'm unable to get it to compile.  I either get 'Pointers may only be used in an unsafe context' or 'You can only take the address of an unfixed expression inside of a fixed statement initializer'.

Comment: right.  You just pass it as a byte array... fixing is not required. `public static extern unsafe short GetIDBuffer(IntPtr hCom, ref byte dataFlag, ref byte count,byte[] value, ref byte stationNum);`

Comment: Thanks, changed my answer using your info.

Comment: @Phil although my problem wasn't solved, your answer was very helpful. Thank you

Comment: Is there any documentation for your library?  That may help.

Comment: The documentation is pretty poor.  No help at all.  I can load your .dll and call it with IntPtr.Zero with no errors.  What size of buffer have you tried?  Are you still getting the same error?  I updated the answer about corflags.

Comment: It looks like it's working. From the documentation "ID Data: tag data, the first byte as tag type, when the tag type as 9, ID length is 4 bytes, and it is tag ID from the second byte to fifth byte, the sixth byte is tag status". The data coming back in your video is 9 0 16 40 144 131 corresponds t tag type=9, id = 0 16 40 144, status=131.  Attempting to convert to a string may fail I guess.

Comment: @Phil attempting to convert to a string failed, available tag ids : 00102890 00102943 00102836. i cant figure out how to get these values.

Comment: Yes, the data doesn't represent a string. It's an array of tags.  You have to parse the bytes, .e.g if first byte is 9 then next 4 are and id, next byte is status, next byte is a new tag id, etc.  I think you're on your own now.

Comment: problem solved: string hex = BitConverter.ToString(bytes).Replace("-", string.Empty); converting the array of bytes to string returned the tag ids

Answer (score 2):

Your definition for Count is wrong, it should be a `ref byte` not a `ref Uint` based on the the native prototype.  If you change it to the correct type and are initializing it with the value you are passing into the StringBuilder constructor everything should work... if it doesn't I would take a step back and use a byte array instead  of a StringBuilder to help get a better idea of what the unmanaged code is doing.

edit:

The error you are getting indicates there is a buffer overflow

```
[DllImport("Reader2.dll")]
public static extern  short GetIDBuffer(IntPtr hCom, ref byte DataFlag, ref byte Count,**(type)** value , ref byte StationNum);

static  void Main(string[] args)
{

    byte count = 0, station = 1, flag = 0; //this right here is probably your problem
    IntPtr hcom = IntPtr.Zero;
```

The unmanaged code you are calling has no way to know how big the buffer you are passing in is.  If your API is sane you will initialize the count variable to let the callee know the size of the buffer.

If this is not the case you will need to look at the documentation to find out how large of a buffer you need to supply.

If neither of these are true we have to assume that the return value is the number of bytes written and, since this is a short, that you need to pass in a buffer that is at least 65,535 bytes long.

If none of these work you will need to call the vendor and find out how to specify the size of the buffer as this doesn't really look to be an interop problem per se.

You also don't need to use `fixed` at all.  The purpose of fixed is to allow you to supply a pointer that will be used between multiple unmanaged calls or to write managed code that is slightly faster (due to no bounds checking) since neither of these apply use a byte array.

your finished code should look something like:

```
[DllImport("Reader2.dll")]
public static extern short GetIDBuffer(IntPtr hCom, ref byte dataFlag, ref byte count,byte [] value, ref byte stationNum);

// ...
byte[] value = new byte[65536];
byte count = 255; //does 255 imply some buffer size?

short len = GetIDBuffer(hCom, ref dataFlag, ref count,value, ref stationNum);
var s1 = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(value,0,count);
var s2 = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(value,0,len);
Console.WriteLine("using count gives\""+s1+"\"");
Console.WriteLine("using return value gives\""+s2+"\"");
```

Comment: you're right and wrong.  byte is best but UInt will work in this instance.  See my answer below.

Comment: @phil yes that is correct for values less then 255... however it looks from his comments like he is passing in a 1000 byte buffer so he will get silently misinterpreted data instead of a compile time error.  In any case the problem is most likely that he is treating count as an out instead of an in/out variable.

Comment: THank you problem solved: string hex = BitConverter.ToString(bytes).Replace("-", string.Empty); converting the array of bytes to string returned the tag ids

Answer (score 0):

Try using SafeHandle rather than IntPtr in your P/Invoke.  It's possible that the managed wrapper around `hCom` is getting GC'd and finalized in the middle of your native call, rendering `hCom` invalid.

Comment: huh? It looks like he is using a solely unmanaged handle with the only managed reference to it being an IntPtr which is just an int the size of a void*... I'm not sure how garbage collection could come in to play.